# How to correctly work with class libraries in ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework) application

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have created a new ASP.NET Core web application (.NET Framework) in Visual Studio.

[image]

This application is intedned to use windows authentication so this was chosen as an option when creating the project.

[image]

I am trying to export my Models and Repository code out to their respective external class library projects but cannot get it to work. Has anyone have any experience of this?

What should the project.json files look like in each class library if i need to reference them in main web project etc.

The prject.json file generated by Visual Studio contains the following code.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": { }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Do I create a Class Library (.NET Core) application and alter it to be compatible with my .NET framework application? If so, what altercations are needed?

I have searched the web but cannot find much information on this scenario.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to use Visual Studio 2017. `project.json` doesn't exist in new version anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by `cannot get it to work`? Which exact error you faced? Your scenario should work by default.

Comment: The error I get when trying to add a migration using dotnet ef command is the following "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.CommandException: No project was found. Change the current working directory or use the --project option". I have tried to execute these commands from my Repositories project, targeting the same framework and I have also tried to run the command when all my model and repository files are in my web project. I have tried also explicitly targeting the project as suggested in the error